# How can I disable parallel build for a certain project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-c++-2015

Two of my projects require gigantic amounts of RAM for compiling.
I already figured out, how to make certain, that they do not build in parallel
-- by specifying build order.
Now I also want to make certain, that there are not multiple .cpp files being compiled from the same project in parallel with the one which is critical.
Anybody any clue?
But I definitely want to keep the parallel build option enabled for all the other projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `/MP` argument to the build, as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385193.aspx).

Comment: So this option is not really a compiler option but a build-system-option?